# Print out tree contents so that each parent covers all its children

Tags: python, function, recursion, tree, tuples

Part of the problem requires that each parent should cover all of its children. If the parent string is too short underscores are added. Any remaining space has periods added.

*** Note: input trees can have any number of children ***

So far I have a function (add_brackets) that adds brackets to each string per the specifications for the problem. It is in these brackets the underscores are added if needed.

The second function (underscores) calculates how many underscores are required.

The last function prints out the tree in level-order recursively.

My current thoughts are that I need to apply the underscores function in the add_brackets function and have add_brackets when printing in the level-order but I am having trouble putting it all together.

```
def add_brackets(x):
  row = ''
  for i in x:
    row = row+'['+i+']'
  return row

def underscores(node):
  parent, children = node
  num = 0
  for child in children:
    num += len(child)+2
  num -= 2
  if len(parent) > canlen:
    return 
  return '_'*num

def level_order(*nodes):
    if not nodes:
      return 
    labels,childrens = zip(*nodes)
    print(add_brackets(labels))
    flattened_children = [c for children in childrens for c children]  
    level_order(*flattened_children)

tree = eval(input('Enter tree: '))
print(level_order(tree))
```

The following tree,

```
tree = ("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
```

Should have output,

```
[hello_____]
[a][b______]
...[cde][fg]
```

and,

```
tree = ("supercalifragilisticexpialidocious",(("a",(("b",(("candy",()),)),("onomatopoeia",()),)),("d",(("egg",(("f",()),)),)),))
```

Should be,

```
[supercalifragilisticexpialidocious]
[a__________________][d__]..........
[b____][onomatopoeia][egg]..........
[candy]..............[f]............
```

How do I add the correct amount of underscores and periods?

Comment: `flattened_children = [c for children in childrens for c children]`
What did you mean to achieve by this line?

Comment: Also, Is there any particular reason you are not using a custom class implementation to structure the data and instead chose so many nested tuples? 
I guess it would be much more clear to write after defining a custom Node class that contains as an attribute the data and it's children as a list of the same object type

Comment: The problem specifies to use tuples to represent the tree. That's the only reason. @ch0wner

Comment: Well can you use tuples as input and parse them into Node objects? This would make the code much cleaner.

Comment: Here's how I'd solve it: create a funtion that calculates the max length of children labels that a node can have, that is recursively checking the length of the children labels concated after being added the square brackets to determine the number of underscores that need to be added. Then, use `str.ljust` to justify the label according to that length - 2 for the square brackets you will add to this current label.

Comment: By the way some comments about the code you have already written. The `add_brackets` function could be rewritten as oneliner. You have identifiers in the code named `x` and `y`, They do not mean anything and you should always use meaningful variables. The `underscores` function does not calculate the length correctly you should rewrite it. Flattening the children is not needed, you can use tuple unpacking while iterating on the nodes e.g. `for label, children in nodes:`.

Comment: Well actually, a better solution would be to start from the leaves in the tree and go up. You should have a two dimensional list that will store the output and then print it after going all over tree from the bottom to the top. This way you can determine the amount of underscores and dots that needs to be added in the most efficient way.

Comment: Yeah ok, I think I see what you mean, makes sense. Thanks for the advice on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the problem you describe and it was more work than I anticipated (though less than 1,500 bytes of code.)  The basic model is to work bottom up to get the underscores and then bottom down to get the padding.  Here's an outline of the functions I defined to solve it:

```
def height_tree(node):
```

Recursive, depth first.  Simple code to calculate the height of the tree.  This is only needed by the next function to distinguish between a node like `[a]` that has no children but needs one faked up for the padding to work and and a node that has no children for which we don't want to add fake ones.

```
def covered_tree(node, level=0):
```

Recursive, depth first.  Recurses first then works out underscore coverage widths.  If `level` is defaulted to zero, sets it to `height_tree()` above.  Returns a valid tree:

```
('[hello_____]', (('[a]', (('...', ()),)), ('[b______]', (('[cde]', ()), ('[fg]', ())))))
```

but parent strings have been extended with brackets and underscores. Gives nodes like `[a]` and `[onomatopoeia]` faked up childred consisting of period padding.

```
def padded_tree(node, tail=True):
```

Recursive, depth first.  Works out padding first then recurses.  Only handles the padding at the right most end of branch, internal padding was handled by `covered_tree()` above.  Returns a valid tree:

```
('[supercalifragilisticexpialidocious]', (('[a__________________]', (('[b____]', (('[candy]', ()),)), ('[onomatopoeia]', (('..............', ()),)))), ('[d__]..........', (('[egg]..........', (('[f]............', ()),)),))))
```

but parent strings have been extended with period padding.

```
def print_tree(node, line_width=0):
```

Iterative, breadth first.  Prints tree, setting `line_width` to the width of the top node, as it *covers* all.  Counts down printing width until it hits zero, outputs a newline, and resets the printing width back to `line_width`.

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> tree = ("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
>>> print_tree(padded_tree(covered_tree(tree)))
[hello_____]
[a][b______]
...[cde][fg]
>>> 
>>> tree = ("supercalifragilisticexpialidocious",(("a",(("b",(("candy",()),)),("onomatopoeia",()),)),("d",(("egg",(("f",()),)),)),))
>>> print_tree(padded_tree(covered_tree(tree)))
[supercalifragilisticexpialidocious]
[a__________________][d__]..........
[b____][onomatopoeia][egg]..........
[candy]..............[f]............
>>>
```

> I don't quite understand how covered_tree function works. Can you
>   elaborate please?

Since this is a critical function, let's break it down:

```
def covered_tree(node, level=0):
```

If `level` is zero, the default, set `level` to the result of `height_tree(node)`.  Split node up into its two parts, a parent (label) and a list of children (nodes).

Do our recursion, creating a new list of children (nodes) that is the result of calling `covered_tree()` on each child, but passing `level - 1` explicitly.  For each of these new children, sum the `len()` (width) of the their labels.  From this tally, subtract the `len()` (width) of our parent label and a width of 2 to account for the brackets.

Now we're ready to create our return node.  It's a tuple that consists of: our parent formatted with brackets plus the number of underscores we just calculated in the previous step; our new list of children. However, if there are *no* children, *and* `level` is greater than one, then instead of empty children, we return a faked up list of children consisting of a child whose label is a string of periods, and whose own children are an empty tuple (i.e. our empty list of children.)  The length of this period string is again `len()` (width) of our parent label plus 2 to account for brackets:

```
('[hello_____]', (('[a]', (('...', ()),)), ('[b______]', (('[cde]', ()), ('[fg]', ())))))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how covered_tree function works. Can you elaborate please? @cdlane

Comment: @Z.Ken, I've added a more detailed explanation of `covered_tree()` to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering how you added the faked list of children, i.e the periods, and checking if  _no_ children _and_ level is greater than one is true? @cdlane